# Loop Through Multivalue Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, object

First of all sorry if I have the terminology wrong, if so could you please correct me?

I am trying to loop through the following javascript array.

```
        var pieData2 = [
            {
                label: 'wow',
                value: 30,
                color:"#F38630"
            },
            {
                label: 'wow2',
                value : 10,
                color : "#E0E4CC"
            },
            {
                label: 'wow3',
                value : 100,
                color : "#69D2E7"
            }

        ];
```

I am trying to write the label and color into separate divs. I have tried the following concept, but have got no where.

```
     $.each( pieData2[0], function( key, value ) {
       alert( key + ": " + value );
         });
```

Comment: Try dropping the `[0]`.

Comment: What should be the output?

Comment: You don't need to specify that it's a "multivalue" array, since arrays are designed to contain multiple values; just call it an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/1119/

```
var pieData2 = [
            {
                label: 'wow',
                value: 30,
                color:"#F38630"
            },
            {
                label: 'wow2',
                value : 10,
                color : "#E0E4CC"
            },
            {
                label: 'wow3',
                value : 100,
                color : "#69D2E7"
            }

        ];

$.each( pieData2, function( key, value ) {
    alert( key + ": " + value['label'] +"  value: " + value['value']);
         });
```

Comment: Perfect, record reply too.

Answer (score 5):

The `jQuery.each()` function is designed to iterate over a collection, such as the elements in an array or over the properties of an object. In your case, it's iterating over an array of objects. In your code, `pieData2` is your array, so you want to pass that as the first argument to `$.each()`. The second argument is a function that will handle each iteration, and has two parameters: `index` and `value` (though you can name them whatever you wish).

```
$.each(pieData2, function(index, value) {
    // index will be 0, 1, 2
    // value will be equivalent to pieData2[0], pieData2[1], pieData2[2]
    console.log(value.label); // outputs wow, wow2, wow3
});
```

As has been used in another answer, you can also use the `this` keyword to refer to the element being looked at for that iteration, so `this` and `value` in the above code are the same.

Comment: ... `console.log(value.value); // outputs wow, wow2, wow3` ... nope .. rather "30, 10, 100" ... :)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair You're right, I looked at the wrong property!

Answer (score 1):

each is fine, but you need to loop over pieData2 not over the first element of pieData2...

```
   $.each( pieData2, function() {
          alert( this.label + ": " + this.value );
     });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3anAJ/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$.each( pieData2, function(index) {
    alert("label = " +pieData2[index].label+ " color = " +pieData2[index].color);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need jQuery for this. In cases where jQuery really isn't needed, I don't really suggest it. At that point it's just kind of pointless. Use regular JS where possible, use jQuery where needed.

```
for (var i = 0; i < pieData2.length; i++) {
    alert(pieData2[i].label + ' : ' + pieData2[i].value);
}
```

If you really want to use jQuery, since `$.each` can iterate over arrays AND objects, you can just use it to iterate over the array and alert each.

This will iterate over each object in the array and alert each key, value pair...

```
$.each(pieData2, function (key, obj) {
    alert(obj.label + ' : ' + obj.value);
});
```

If you need to iterate over the array and over each object (if you do not know the length), then you can do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < pieData2.length; i++) {
    for (var prop in pieData2[i]) {
        if (pieData2[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            alert(prop + ' : ' + pieData2[i][prop]);
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
$.each(pieData2, function(obj) {
    $.each(pieData2[obj], function(key, value) {
        alert(key + ' : ' + value);
    });
});
```